# Standing While Loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, counter

I am trying to make a word counter by fragmenting the sentence into individual words. I try to accomplish this by using the split method (for the object String). However, I am having trouble counting the words because the loop is terminating mid-way. Can you help me?

Desired: To find out how many times a word in a String repeats.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0, i=0;
    int max,a;
    ArrayList<Integer> lastCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String yazi ="How ı can do that? I don't know. Can you help me? I need help for counter. Thanks in advance for all.";
    String yazi1 = yazi.replace(",","");
    yazi1 = yazi1.replace(".", "");
    yazi1 = yazi1.replace("?", "");
    yazi1 = yazi1.replace("!", "");
    yazi1 = yazi1.toLowerCase();
    yazi1 = yazi1.replace("ı", "i");
    String[] words = yazi1.split(" ");
    for(a=0; a < words.length; a++) {
        while(i<words.length){
            if(words[a].equals(words[i])) {
                max = 0;
                lastCount.add(a, max+1);
            }
            i++;
        } 
        System.out.println(a+1 +". Word: " + words[a] + " || Counter: "+lastCount.get(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: By *"The loop is stopping"* it appears that you mean *"I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out-of-bounds for length 1"*. Please be specific in how the program fails to work correctly

Comment: Or did you perhaps mean that the **`while`** loop only works the first time, i.e. when `a == 0`? If so, it is because you never reset `i` back to 0. Don't declare variables before they are needed. You would likely have avoided this problem if you has done `int i=0;` inside the `for` loop, instead of declaring `i` at the top.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to debug too many, but I could not fix it. For the first time, I have been very careful with the question and the elimination. Next time I'll be more careful. @Andreas

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should initialize `max` and `a`; it clears confusion and makes it easier to read. Second of all, you should use a nested for loop instead of a for loop and while loop. Thirdly, I believe that once `i` reaches `words.length`, you don't **reset** it back to 0. When `a` is 0, `i` goes to `words.length`, and iteration 1 is completed. `a` goes to 1, but `i` is still `words.length`, so nothing happens. This repeats until `a` becomes `words.length`, and the program reaches a stop. Almost nothing was accomplished. I believe this problem could have been fixed by making both `a` and `i` local variables that exist only in the for loops. The code should become:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int count = 0;
int max = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> lastCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String yazi ="How ı can do that? I don't know. Can you help me? I need help for counter. Thanks in advance for all.";
String yazi1 = yazi.replace(",","");
yazi1 = yazi1.replace(".", "");
yazi1 = yazi1.replace("?", "");
yazi1 = yazi1.replace("!", "");
yazi1 = yazi1.toLowerCase();
yazi1 = yazi1.replace("ı", "i");
String[] words = yazi1.split(" ");
for(int a=0; a < words.length; a++) {
    for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(words[a].equals(words[i])) {
            max = 0;
            lastCount.add(a, max+1);
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(a+1 +". Word: " + words[a] + " || Counter: "+lastCount.get(a));
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, the loop is working, but the number of counters is only increasing once. He's seen only once, despite having the same word @Roham Bhowmik

Comment: @Nosteam It doesn't matter how many times during the iteration of the `i` loop that the `if` statement is true, because the code will do the *same* thing every time. `max = 0` followed by `lastCount.add(a, max+1)` is the same as `lastCount.add(a, 1)`, so for e.g. `a = 0`, even if `words` is an array of 10 times the same word, the code will just execute `lastCount.add(0, 1)` ten times, resulting in `lastCount` containing `{0=1}`. Your code is not actually *counting* anything.